# need to move files with name into directories with corresponding names

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting, directory, command

I have files named

> patient_sample_L001_R1_001, patient_sample_L002_R1_001,
>   patient_sample_L003_R1_001, patient_sample_L004_R1_001

another set named

> patient_sample_L001_R1_002, patient_sample_L002_R1_002,
>   patient_sample_L003_R1_002, patient_sample_L004_R1_002,

and so on and so forth. For each set of 4 files (with different end numbers 001,002,003) i need to move it into an appropriate directory labelled patient0001, or patient 0002, and so on and so forth. I have around 200 of these sets. Is there a command I can do that scans for files with a different end number and puts it into the appropriate patient folder?

i.e patient_sample_L001_R1_001,
patient_sample_L002_R1_001,
patient_sample_L003_R1_001,
patient_sample_L004_R1_001,
 goes into "patient0001 folder and etc.

Each of these files are in different directories. For example main directory has a directory called run40 in it there is the patient1 data. Then in run41 there is the patient 2 data and etc.. back in the main directory there is another directory called "total_patient_samples"that is where you can find all the directories that i want to move the files from the "run40, run41" directories into. In that file there is patient0001, patient 0002, patient 0003. I would like the aforementioned data files to go into there.

Comment: Is renaming f.ex. `run40` to `patient0001` a possibility?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `tree` in `run41`, `run41` and `total_patient_samples`. It is hard to understand your description. Are the directiories in `total_patient_samples` actually named `patient0001` or `patient 0001` or is it `patient001` as in the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
cd total_patient_samples
find ../ -name patient_sample_\* | while read -r i; do
    pnum="${i##*_}"
    mkdir -p "patient$pnum"
    mv -v "$i" "patient$pnum"
done
```

This depends sensitively on the exact names of the files, so it's good to be careful.

EDIT: Updated code according to comment below. This will grab any file under the main directory that matches `patient_sample_*`, so make sure there aren't any you don't want to move.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for i in `seq -f '%03g' 1 200`; do
    FOLDER=patient0$i
    mkdir -p total_patient_samples/$FOLDER    # creates folder if missing
    find . -regex ".*patient_sample_L00._R._${i}$" -type f -exec mv -i {} total_patient_samples/$FOLDER/ \; # moves patient data if not already there, else prompts
done
```

This cycles `i` from 001 to 200 (change the 200 if necessary), creates the patient-folder (remove the `mkdir ...` line if not needed), finds all patients of the structure you specified, and moves them into the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this:

```
for file in patient*; do
 PATIENT_NO=$(echo $file | sed 's/patient_sample_.*R1_\(.*\)/\1/')
 PATIENT_DIR=patient$PATIENT_NO
 mkdir -p $PATIENT_DIR
 mv $file $PATIENT_DIR
done
```

At first we cut with `sed` the patient number, then construct directory name and move file into it.